# How to make this c# code small or refactor this code

Tags: c#

I am new with coding and I recently read article about code refactoring. So I have made a console application for booking rooms in a ship. I think in my project there are only 2 part where I need refactoring, which are as follows.
One is if else statement.

```
        ship1 = new Ship("Olympic Countess");

        ArrayList groupA = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupA.Add(new room(5000, "A" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupB = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupB.Add(new room(4000, "B" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupC = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            groupC.Add(new room(3500, "C" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupD = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            groupD.Add(new room(3400, "D" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupE = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            groupE.Add(new room(3300, "E" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupF = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            groupF.Add(new room(3400, "F" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupG = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            groupG.Add(new room(3300, "G" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ArrayList groupH = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            groupH.Add(new room(3200, "H" + (i + 1)));
        }

        ship1.addDeck("Balcony Suite", groupA);
        ship1.addDeck("Suite", groupB);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 3 - Outside Twin", groupC);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 2 - Outside Twin", groupD);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 1 - Outside Twin", groupE);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 3 - Inside Twin", groupF);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 2 - Inside Twin", groupG);
        ship1.addDeck("Deck 1 - Inside Twin", groupH);      
    }
```

and the other one is if else statement as follow

```
    public Reservation bookPassage(String cabinclass, Customer booker, int number)
      {
        ArrayList cabins;
        if (cabinclass.Equals("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Balcony Suite");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Suite");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("c", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 3 - Outside Twin");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("d", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 2 - Outside Twin");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("e", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 1 - Outside Twin");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("f", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 3 - Inside Twin");
        else if (cabinclass.Equals("g", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 2 - Inside Twin");
        else 
            cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 1 - Inside Twin");
```

What I don't understand is that my parameters are changing in both logic.
So how can I make a separate method for this logic when my cabin class is changing every time?

Comment: you should probably ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your code works, your question may be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your iterations can be joined together, therefore executed in one run like:

```
ArrayList groupA = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupB = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupC = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupD = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupE = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupF = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupG = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList groupH = new ArrayList(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {           
        if (i < 10)
        {
            groupA.Add(new room(5000, "A" + (i + 1)));
            groupB.Add(new room(4000, "B" + (i + 1)));
        }
        if (i < 30)
        {
            groupF.Add(new room(3400, "F" + (i + 1)));
            groupC.Add(new room(3500, "C" + (i + 1)));
        }
        if (i < 40)
        {
            groupE.Add(new room(3300, "E" + (i + 1)));
            groupH.Add(new room(3200, "H" + (i + 1)));          
        }
        if (i < 36)
        {
            groupD.Add(new room(3400, "D" + (i + 1)));
            groupG.Add(new room(3300, "G" + (i + 1)));
        }               
    }

    ship1.addDeck("Balcony Suite", groupA);
    ship1.addDeck("Suite", groupB);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 3 - Outside Twin", groupC);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 2 - Outside Twin", groupD);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 1 - Outside Twin", groupE);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 3 - Inside Twin", groupF);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 2 - Inside Twin", groupG);
    ship1.addDeck("Deck 1 - Inside Twin", groupH);
```

and the bunch of mutually exclusive ifs can be joined in a cse lik:

```
    switch (cabinclass.ToLower())
{
    case "a":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Balcony Suite");
        break;
    case "b":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Suite");
        break;
    case "c":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 3 - Outside Twin");
        break;
    case "d":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 2 - Outside Twin");
        break;
    case "e":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 1 - Outside Twin");
        break;
    case "f":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 3 - Inside Twin");
        break;
    case "g":
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 2 - Inside Twin");
        break;
    default:
        cabins = ship1.getDeck("Deck 1 - Inside Twin");
        break;              
}
```

Comment: Nice, you could even reduce the number of if statements by adding to the lists in reverse and grouping together (i.e less than 40 first to add e and h, then less than 36 second to add d and g)

Comment: thank you @sayse and everyone else who replied i think i got some of it and i will try to implement it now thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this piece of code there are most likely many more parts in your code that should (or could) be refactored.

Lets start by extracting constants. Just put each constant string (like "Deck 1 - Inside Twin") into a const. This will help you if you ever try to rename any of the decks.

Then you should stick to common coding conventions. Class names in C# always start upper case (rename `room` to `Room`).

Then you can extract a method from

```
new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    groupC.Add(new room(3500, "C" + (i + 1)));
}
```

Then instead of your if-statement you could use a `Dictionary` or something similar to extract the correct deck, which would simply remove the if-then-else.

Probably a lot more you can refactor to make your code better :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized function.

E.g. in

```
    ArrayList groupC = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        groupC.Add(new room(3500, "C" + (i + 1)));
    }
```

the items differ are: groupC, 30, 3500 and "C".

Make a method with above items as argument and call that method with the correct parameters for every fragment.